# Do SMO assemblies have to be explicitely referenced when compiling a C# program?

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-assembly

I am developing a c# program that uses `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo`. In order to compile it, I need to explicitely reference the corresponding assemblies:

```
csc -reference:"c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll" ...
```

I am wondering if this is expected. I have assumed that these assemblies were somehow "registered" (if this is the correct terminology) when SQL Server was installed so that they are found by the compiler and runtime environment when needed.

If they were not registered, is it possible to register them?

Comment: AFAIK, normally the reference would be added to the project, and all such references are passed on the command-line to `csc`.  It needs to be done unless the assembly is in the GAC.

Comment: Compile times would skyrocket if all DLLs installed on the system were automatically referenced, and think about the version problems. Why are you using the command line compiler to start with?

Comment: @CodeCaster I take your argument to mean that everything is ok on my machine if I have to reference the assemblies. I use the command line because I have not yet come across a viable alternative.

Comment: Use Visual Studio Code or Visual Studio Community? You can then make a project file in which you organise your references. So yes, having to manually tell the compiler which non-standard libraries you want to reference, is normal. :)

Comment: There are numerous build systems available.  For example: MSBuild, Cake.  Why aren't these viable solutions?

Comment: @Amy, maybe these are alternatives. As I said, I did not come across them yet.

Comment: Also, consider _strongly_ not referencing SMO.  It's a library that appears to make your life easier, but for many scenarios simply using SqlClient and TSQL ends up being easier to code, compile, and deploy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an IDE like Visual Studio, references would normally be added from the Solution Explorer->References->Add reference and these are automatically passed down to the compiler at compile time. Without an IDE that supports this, you have to manually pass them down to the `csc` as a command line argument (like you're doing). If you can't afford VS, you can go for the Community Edition of VS, or try another free IDE like MonoDevelop, or use a build script/system like CMake to handle it.